# ActiveScaffold for PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, frameworks

Ruby on Rails has a bunch of plugins which extend the normal scaffolding:

- [Lipsiadmin](http://groups.google.com/group/lipsiadmin)
- [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/)
- [Streamlined](http://github.com/relevance/streamlined/tree/master)
- [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/)

Does the PHP community have anything similar?  phpmyadmin is great, but it doesn't have any way to control the presentation of the data.  You always get all of the data in its presentation format.  These Rails frameworks are a little more user friendly.

*Edit: My original question was not very clear.  I'm not looking to compare PHP and Rails.  I'm also not looking for an all purpose general framework.  I'm looking for something just like the four pieces of software I listed above, but written in PHP.  The admin software I listed above generates a crud interface for you based on your configuration.  The configuration includes which tables you'd like to show, what operations you can do to the table, and who can see the information.  The software does the rest, from writing the SQL to processing the request to generating the interface.*

Comment: I think you're mixing things up. What does phpmyadmin has to do with it?

Comment: I think what Dave is trying to say or is looking for is a quick way to visualize a database/tables with view/add/edit pages, but a tool flexible/customizable enough to be able to alter these visualizations ... I'm looking for something similar ...

Comment: The question is definitely a bit confused.  Ruby is a language, and Rails is a framework.  In order to compare Rails functionality to PHP, you'd need to be comparing it to a PHP framework.  The question is really "Is there a PHP framework that it similar to Rails?"

Comment: That is exactly correct.  I was afraid people would answer my question with phpmyadmin, so I was trying to explain how it would not meet my criteria.

Comment: zombat: I'm looking for a php framework / plugin / addon / module / library or whatever you'd like to call it.  I'm not comparing Rails functionality to PHP.  I'm trying to get the functionality of the Rails addons in a php addon.

Comment: It's a good question, you might just want to edit it for clarity.  I'm not overly familiar with Rails, so I don't know the answer, but I'm definitely interested in what the answer is.

Comment: Right. I think you're looking for a PHP framework, with some advanced tools like those you mention. Something like django, you could say. I believe PHP has nothing as such, yet. But I'd be happy to know too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117406/which-php-framework-is-closest-to-ruby-on-rails-cakephp-codeigniter

Comment: PHP itself doesn't have anything like this, but one of the frameworks probably does.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/community/framework), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com/). See if they have an addon or plugin that can do it.

The problem with the four pieces of software you listed is that they extend Rails. When you say "PHP," there is nothing to extend in the same sense. (I really doubt you want a PHP module that does this.) You don't need a PHP addon, you need a [framework] addon.

Any of the frameworks I or Jonathan listed are similar to Rails. Kohana in particular has an addon module called [Auto Modeler](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/projects/automodeler) that may do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at pear: http://pear.php.net/

Comment: I have.  Pear is great for low level PHP tools.  What I'm looking for is a higher level framework similar to the admin plugins of Rails.  Something where I can configure basic crud operations on data I choose and get off and running very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to stress the difference between a language and a framework here.  PHP is not itself a framework with modules.  PHP is a language, like C or Python.

There are several website frameworks that have been written in PHP.  The most popular would probably be [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) though there are several that I've looked at over the last year that seem similarly capable:

- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/)
- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
- [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/)

[PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is not a module or a framework.  It is a separate, stand-alone web application for database administration, written in PHP.  It won't be a component in any strategy for presentation of data on a website.

Comment: My original post was not very clear.  Please read the edit clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony may be a "general framework", but it has scaffolding you can use as a complete application if your needs are simple. You define your model in a YML config file, and can then generate CRUD modules based on this model. The code generation is also customizable by editing other YML config files. All without writing any PHP code. But should the need arise, you have the option to extend the scaffolding with PHP and the complete framework.

See the Symfony [docs on code generation](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/14-Generators#Scaffolding).

[A framework called ATK](http://www.atk-framework.com/) also claims a good code:functionality ratio ("An application in 10 lines of code").